# Why the path alias is like http://domain/http://domain/path?

Tags: path-aliases

Adding a simple alias for media [media:url] causes the domain to be listed twice in the URL on media listing page in admin, for example http://domain/http://domain/path. How do I change it to http://domain/path?

Comment: Does it have subtokens? Eg media:url:relative

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different token which fixed the issue. I believe using token URL in the URL field is the cause of the double URLs.